# isEmpty issue while comparing java object

Tags: java, object, is-empty

Currenty I have this NULL object for Employee Details to pass if employee details object created is empty

```
public static final EmployeeDetails NULL = new EmployeeDetails();
```

But I want to remove this now and use my regular EmployeeDetails object.

I was checking EmployeeDetails obj is empty or not by doing this `if(!EmployeeDetails.NULL.equals(empDetails))`

but now I dont have that object so I won't be able to do that way. I tried this way but got error saying isEmpty is not defined.

```
if(!empDetails.isEmpty())
```

Can someone tell me what I am suppose to do with this.

Thanks

Comment: Well it sounds like you haven't created an `isEmpty` method. Java isn't going to create that for you...

Comment: I thought isempty was inbuilt.. What do I have to check inside isEmpty method to see if object is empty

Comment: It's not inbuilt. What does it mean to be "empty" for an object you defined? How would the compiler know? Have you tried reading a tutorial on Java and OOP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isEmpty()` is not defined because you did not define it. This funciton is not included in the handful of methods you get directly from Object and, in any case, an empty condition for your own objects should be defined by you since only you know the internal structure.

Of course, it all depends on what do you need because one person can take an `isEmpty()` method as valid by doing a simple null check while other person can make a field-by-field check.

In your case, just define an isEmpty method in your class. For example:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    //your condition here, for example, I take an EmployeeDetails object
    //as empty if it has no employee associated (assuming you can associate
    //an employee to it).
    return employee == null;
}
```

Remember to define WHEN do you consider this object to be empty and code the method with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method public boolean isEmpty() { // Implementation } ... here add your logic to find out the empty object, for example your previous  code was checking the default value for all the properties to find out empty